# Error dereferencing pointer to incomplete type and I can't figure out why

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I've went thru all the material here and I just can't seem to spot my error.
I've created some structs to be used and when trying to manipulate them I get this error. Any advice would be appriciated!

These are the structs as defined in KDArray.c

```
    struct sp_kdarray_t
    {
        SPPoint* points;
        int** sorted;
        int rows;
        int size;
    };
    struct sp_kdarrays_t
    {
        SPKDArray kdLeft;
        int leftSize;
        int rightSize;
        SPKDArray kdRight;
    };
```

And in KDArray.h we have:

```
    typedef struct sp_kdarray_t* SPKDArray;
    typedef struct sp_kdarrays_t* SPKDArrays;
```

Now when I try to manipulate them ( recursively building a tree ) in the following function:

```
    KDTreeNode recursiveTreeBuild(SPKDArray kdArr, int size, SP_TREE_SPLIT_METHOD spKDTreeSplitMethod, int splittingDimension)
    {

        int split;
        KDTreeNode result;

        result = (KDTreeNode)malloc(sizeof(KDTreeNode));
        if (result == NULL)
        {
            spLoggerPrintError("Memory Allocation ERROR", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
            return NULL;
        }

        if (size == 1)
        {
            result -> dim = -1;
            result -> val = -1;
            result -> left = NULL;
            result -> right = NULL;
            result -> data = spKDArrayCopyPoint(kdArr, 0);
            if (result -> data == NULL)
            {
                spLoggerPrintError("Memory Allocation ERROR", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SPKDArrays subtrees;

            subtrees = spKDArraySplit(kdArr, splittingDimension);
            if (subtrees == NULL)
                return NULL;

            result -> dim = splittingDimension;
            result -> val = spKDArrayGetMedianValueByDimension(kdArr, splittingDimension);
            result -> data = NULL;
            switch (spKDTreeSplitMethod)
            {
                case MAX_SPREAD:
                    split = spKDArrayGetHighestSpread(kdArr);
                    if (split < 0)
                        return NULL;
                    break;
                case RANDOM:
                    srand(time(NULL));
                    split = rand() % spKDArrayGetDimensions(kdArr);
                    break;
                case INCREMENTAL:
                    split =  splittingDimension + 1;
                    break;
            }
            result -> left = recursiveTreeBuild(subtrees -> kdLeft, subtrees -> leftSize, spKDTreeSplitMethod, split);
            result -> right = recursiveTreeBuild(subtrees -> kdRight, subtrees -> rightSize, spKDTreeSplitMethod, split);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I get the "dereferencing error" on :

```
            result -> left = recursiveTreeBuild(subtrees -> kdLeft, subtrees -> leftSize, spKDTreeSplitMethod, split);
            result -> right = recursiveTreeBuild(subtrees -> kdRight, subtrees -> rightSize, spKDTreeSplitMethod, split);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `KDTreeNode`? Is it a typedef of a pointer?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: As a general rule, structs should be defined in header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error happens because the compiler cannot find the definition of the `struct`. The definition is there, but it is probably in the wrong file or in the wrong position in the file. You don't give details on the layout of your project so I cannot be sure of the details...

For example, the following code will trigger the same error:

```
typedef struct foo_t* Foo;

void something1(Foo p)
{
    p->whatever; // error: incomplete type!
}
struct foo_t // type definition
{
    int whatever;
};
void something2(Foo p)
{
    p->whatever; // ok: the type is complete
}
```

So you should move the definition of the structs to before the function, or maybe to the header file itself.

Or if you want the structs to work as opaque types, so you don't want to publicly define them, the usual way is to write a public header with the declarations and a private header with the definitions.

Comment: @LPs: Hmm... true. But I was looking at the other structs, not that one, because if `KDTreeNode` was an incomplete type you'd have a lot of errors before the ones noted by OP.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for all the help!@rodrigo I'll provide some details about the project layout: So I've got KDArray.c which is the file where spKDArraySplit() is implemented as well as both of the structs. It includes KDArray.h where the "typedef" for both of those structs is defined as well as functions prototypes (including spKDArraySplit()). The RecursiveBuild() is implemented in KDTree.c which includes KDTree.h which includes KDArray.h. I can't seem to find the error point as it functions properly up to this point and all the includes are working i guess..

Comment: @doria90: `RecursiveBuild()` is in `KDTree.c`, that includes `KDTree.h` with the typedef declarations (pointers to incomplete types), but not the definitions. Those are in `KDArray.c`, so they are not visible from `KDTree.c`! Just move the struct definitions to `KDArray.h` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @rodrigo! it helped a lot!